# Which build server and code scan tool to use on AWS EC2 Windows instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, build-server

I have to implement Code Scan tool in CI/CD pipeline in AWS. I have an EC2 Windows Instance.

I checked few tutorials and found some plugins with Jenkins but these all samples are in Linux.

I want to know how to install Jenkins or any other alternative in EC2 Windowsand which code scan tool to use in this environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow [How to Install Jenkins on Windows](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-install-jenkins-on-windows) tutorial to see how you can use Jenkins on windows.

Alternative to Jenkins is [Atlassian Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) which is widely used as well for CI/CD

Some of the widely used code scan tools are

- [Checkmarx](https://www.checkmarx.com/)
- [Sonarqube](https://www.sonarqube.org/)
- [IBM Appscan](https://www.ibm.com/in-en/security/application-security/appscan) - Commercial

Comment: Installing Jenkins on Windows is OK. That I can install. But how to install on AWS EC2 Windows instance? Can it be installed using python command line in Windows Server?

Comment: You can install Jenkins on AWS EC2 Windows instance just like you would on your Windows desktop

Comment: Just make sure that the instance has proper internet connectivity so that you can download the installer

Comment: But on Windows EC2 instance, I am neither able to download Setup nor able to execute it.

Comment: That would be your your EC2 security groups might not be showing it or your EC2 might be in private subnet... Make sure that either your  EC2 is in public subnet or if it is in private subnet then your have a NAT available to the subnet